# Connecting to SNS in Boto and Python

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

I am new to boto and python, trying to connect sns. Here is my sample code:

```
import boto
sns = boto.connect_sns(aws_access_key_id="my access", aws_secret_access_key="mysecret", region_name='us-east-1')
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sns.py", line 5, in <module>
    sns=boto.connect_sns(aws_access_key_id="XXXXXXXX",aws_secret_access_key="XXXXXXX",region_name='us-east-1')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect_sns'
```

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should never post your AWS access tokens online. You probably need to invalidate those tokens now.

Comment: [v2.45.0](https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/develop/boto/__init__.py) seems to have `connect_sns`. What _boto_ version are you using (after `import boto`, `print(boto.__version__)`)?. You could also `print(dir(boto))`.

Answer (score 1):

These days, it is recommended that you use `boto3` rather than `boto` (v2). Here's some sample code:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
response = client.list_topics()
```

See: [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.list_topics)